# json objects in mongod

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am trying to create a user that has a username, password and playlist. The playlist should be an array that holds a json objects which looks like
    {"Songname": upvotecount} which are both a string and number. When I try to create the object, the username and password are created fine, but the playlist won't create properly. I would appreciate any help on how to create this object properly. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
var user = new User({
    username: user,
    password: pass,
    playlist: [{String : Number}]
});
```

Comment: your contents of your playlist array is not valid javascript code. The object getting created in your array is invalid. Should be {songname: <value>, upcountvote: <value>}. You did not provide any keys in the original object definition

Comment: Thank you! I am new to JSON and now understand better how to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of your playlist array is not valid javascript code. The object getting created in your array is invalid. Should be `{songname: <value>, upcountvote: <value>}`. You did not provide any keys in the original object definition

```
var user = new User({
  username: user,
  password: pass,
  playlist: [
    {
      songname: "a song",
      upcount: 1
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!